# Issue with CORS only when using a library

Tags: cors, vuejs3, nuxt3

I ran into an issue when using https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-average-color or any other color library for that matter.

I'm trying to calculate average color from an already loaded image.
All images load on my website just fine, because I have CORS configured properly in the backend.

Surprisingly, using this library yields the following errors:

```
_slug_.c3743e61.js:56 Error: FastAverageColor: security error (CORS) 
for resource https://api.mypage.com/assets/get/310fffca-a463-40ed-ad2e-4d41cee2a1eb.

_slug_.c3743e61.js:57 DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 
'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
```

I'm a bit flabbergasted, as this issue happens nowhere else throughout my app but this specific instance where I use the library.

Here's the image element I'm feeding it:

```html
<img 
    :src='src'
    @load='setBackground'
>
```

Here's my implementation of the function:

```js
    async getAverageColor(img: HTMLImageElement): Promise<IColor>
    {
        const color = await fac.getColor(img);

        return (
            {
                r: color.value[0],
                g: color.value[1],
                b: color.value[2],
                a: color.value[3]
            }
        );
    }
```

Additionally, I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy and haven't had any issues with CORS before.

I'm out of options, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is that a static asset? Are static assets getting CORS applied to them? You can verify this via the browser's development console, in the network tab. Being able to display the image doesn't require CORS. Accessing or altering the content of the image does require CORS.

Comment: @Ouroborus It's a static asset served by backend API. Funnily enough, the `img` DOM element I reference to fetch image from is showing just fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#what_requests_use_cors):

> ### What requests use CORS?
>
> - [...]
> - Images/video frames drawn to a canvas using [`drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage).

And [fast-average-color](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-average-color), the library in question, [uses `drawImage`](https://github.com/fast-average-color/fast-average-color/blob/444afd7af3ba340f230146468e659f957206a6ef/src/index.ts#L138) under the hood.

Adding a [`crossorigin` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/crossorigin) to your `img` an element would solve your issue (under the assumption that the resource in question be configured for CORS). The library's README has a [section](https://github.com/fast-average-color/fast-average-color/tree/444afd7af3ba340f230146468e659f957206a6ef#unhandled-rejection-securityerror-the-operation-is-insecure) about this.

Comment: Yes, and setting `crossOrigin='anonymous'` makes it work-ish.. meaning, I get CORS errors unless I disable the cache.

Comment: Yes, adding a `crossorigin` attribute is the solution.

Comment: sadly it doesn't resolve the issue fully, as it still doesn't work with caching enabled in the browser.

Comment: Have you tried flushing the cache after adding that `crossorigin` attribute?

Comment: Yup, no avail - only having the 'Disable cache' in Chrome Dev Tools makes it work. As soon as I uncheck it, it's breaking again.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in browsers other than Chrome?

Comment: In Edge: Yes, in Firefox: No. Also, when I disabled setting `CacheControl` and `Expires` in the backend, it started working - so I'm assuming there's some weird mumbojumbo between how chrome fetches cached non-CORS images.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=409090

Comment: The issue is that it first caches an image without CORS applied, then it loads it from cache and tries accessing it as if it went through CORS. I've added `Vary` and `AccessControlAllowOrigin: *` to returned assets - seems to work, but I can't be sure.

I'll mark this as an answer as someone might find the comments useful.

Comment: Either configure the resource to always respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, regardless of whether the request contains an `Origin` header. Or add a `Vary: Origin` header to the response; doing so instruct caches to (among other things) treat requests that lack an `Origin` header differently from requests that do contain an `Origin` header. See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-http-caches

Comment: Let me know how it goes. I might consolidate my answer later.

Answer (score 1):

Displaying an image across origins doesn't require permission using CORS (and won't invoke the CORS mechanisms (such as the `Origin` request header) by default).

Reading the image data into JavaScript and processing it **does** require permission using CORS.

The purpose of fast-average-color is to read the image data into JavaScript and calculate the average or dominant color. That is processing and therefore requires permission using CORS.

You can use [the `crossorigin` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/crossorigin) on the `<img>` element to tell the browser that you want to load it with CORS permissions (this will add the `Origin` request header when the image is loaded). (Obviously this requires that the server set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response).

Comment: This works only when the browser cache is disabled for some reason.